# The working copy "app_name" failed to commit files

Tags: xcode, git, commit

After having to do a clean install of my system (macOS Monterey 12.7.3; Xcode 14.0.1), and restoring files using Migration Assistant, when attempting to commit my project (for the first time following the reinstall/restore), I get an error message:

**The working copy "app_name" failed to commit files.** error: invalid object 100644

I have tried some solutions recommended in these and other forums, such as doing an "xcrun git config" command from the console, but no luck.

When I add a file to the project (in a blind effort to solve the problem), sometimes the files mentioned in the error message change, but still, no commit.

I am eager to be able to move on with my project. I appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like the clean install and restore has damaged your Git repo. Is there a remote copy? If so, just throw this one away and clone the remote.

Comment: Alternatively just throw away your repo and start a new one. But of course then you lose the history (though nothing else).

Comment: Matt, no remote repository, and I'd love to be able to keep the project history. Any way to fix the git error and not lose the project history?

Comment: Maybe but you won't do it using Xcode. You need to use the command line and be prepared to dive into the nitty gritty of repo construction.

Comment: I restored by project files directly (via copy) from my Time Machine backup. When I try to do a Commit, the commit message that shows up is different from what is in the .git folder of my project. Does Xcode have a setting somewhere to tell it where to look for the .git folder (other than the project folder)? Perhaps if I can get Xcode to look at the .git folder in my restored project folder things might work again.

Comment: I beg you to forget about Xcode. Just use the Terminal. `cd` into your project folder and say `git status`. Try to do normal actions like `git add .` and `git commit -mtesting`.